# is there an elliptical nearest neighbors regressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am currently using RadiusNeighborsRegressor. I am wondering if there is elliptical neighbors regressor instead of circular.  Thanks

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsRegressor.html

Comment: just scale your data to stretch ellipses to circles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I recall, scikit has no elliptical regressor available.

Nevertheless, you can make us of KDTree with a custom metric
Refer:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#kdtree-and-balltree-classes

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])

# aspect of the axis a, b of the ellipse
aspect = b / a
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('pyfunc', func = lambda p0, p1: math.sqrt((p1[0] - p0[0]) * (p1[0] - p0[0]) + (p1[1] - p0[1]) * (p1[1] - p0[1]) * aspect))
kdt = KDTree(X, leaf_size=30, metric=dist)

# now kdt allows queries with ellipses with aspect := b / a
kdt.query([0.1337, -0.42], k=6)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome. I tried and there is an error: in the line of dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric(), the error is ValueError: metric PyFuncDistance is not valid for KDTree

Comment: Hi, instead of KDTree you can try BallTree which support custom distance metrics
Something for reference: https://notebook.community/rohinkumar/galsurveystudy/old/sklearn_metric_def

Comment: Thanks aryasha2k, yes BallTree works. Here is the code:  X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])    tree = BallTree(X,metric="pyfunc",func=lambda p0, p1: math.sqrt((p1[0] - p0[0]) * (p1[0] - p0[0]) + (p1[1] - p0[1]) * (p1[1] - p0[1]) * aspect))         tree.query([[0.1337, -0.42]], k=6)

Comment: another question is for using BallTRee, I'd like to find neighbor point within the area of ellipse, I am seeing the function of query_radius() which still use radius, how to use area of elipse instead of radius? Thanks

Comment: According to official BallTree Documentation from SciKit, it seems there is no function for utilising the area of ellipse using `query_radius()` to find neighbour point, maybe you could experiment with a custom function for area by manipulating the `query_radius()` function in a way that you are able to define the area of ellipse. 

I'm unsure if this will work, nevertheless you could try...good luck!